# I keep getting an error when extending the 'Application' class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I’m trying to use [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), but I keep getting errors when using anything from JavaFX:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - cannot find symbol
symbol: class Application
```

This is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewClass extends Application {

        public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle circ = new Circle(40, 40, 30);
        Group root = new Group(circ);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        stage.setTitle("My JavaFX Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be your issue: cannot find symbol symbol: class Application

Comment: You tagged this JavaFX 8, but that version is obsolete. Instead, use a modern version by following the advice in mipa’s answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using a JDK which does not contain JavaFX. There are various ways to cope with that. Have a look at the official documentation: *[Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)*